# Backbone.js nested model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am just starting to learn Backbone.js. How do i create a Backbone model for the following use case

- States:[0-n]

  - name
  - counties:[0-n]

    - name
    - cities:[0-n]

      - name:
      - parks[0-n]

        - name:

Any help will is greatly appreciated.
this is what i tries so far

```
window.Team = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(){
          this.id = this.get('id');
        }
      });
      window.Teams = Backbone.Collection.extend({model:Team});

      window.Ward = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(){
          this.name = this.get('name');
          this.code = this.get('code');
          this.teams = new Teams(this.get('teams'));
        }
      });

      window.Wards = Backbone.Collection.extend({model:Ward});

      window.LGA = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(){
          this.name = this.get('name');
          this.wards = new Wards(this.get('wards'));
        }
      });

      window.LGAs = Backbone.Collection.extend({model:LGA});

      window.State = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(){
          this.name = this.get('name');
          this.lgas = new Wards(this.get('lgas'));
        }
      });

      window.States = Backbone.Collection.extend({model:State,

        initialize: function(){
          _.bindAll(this, 'fetch_success');
          this.bind('change', this.fetch_success);
        },

        url: function(){
            return "data.json"
        },

        fetch_success:function(){
            var data = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(someViewWithAForm);
            var model = new Backbone.Model(data);
        }
      });
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us http://whathaveyoutried.com , please. This shows what you have until now and that you are not after `code for free` guys.

Comment: Updated with the code i tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you build/fetch your models, you may be interested in [`Backbone-relational`](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational), which lets you define relationships between models.

From the docs:

```
Person = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations: [
        {
            type: 'HasMany',
            key: 'jobs',
            relatedModel: 'Job',
            reverseRelation: {
                key: 'person'
            }
        }
    ]
});
```